# Single mass insert into database in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to use something like the following, to insert like 1.000.000 statements at once into my database.
But in my model i have a **before_create :build_a_detail** which inserts to every record in user_node_scores an associated record in the other table. they are associated through a has_one, belongs_to relationship and a foreign key..

But how can i maintain this association, with a single mass insert!?

```
inserts = []
TIMES.times do
  inserts.push "(3.0, '2009-01-23 20:21:13', 2, 1)"
end
sql = "INSERT INTO user_node_scores (`score`, `updated_at`, `node_id`, `user_id`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, what you are trying to do here is using an raw sql to insert record, So you could use raw ActiveRecord connection to execute your sql command, (without going through ActiveRecord Model call backs)

Ex:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def raw_sql_insert(sql)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end

end
```

then call `User.new.raw_sql_insert(<your insert sql>)`.

Comment: I am not sure if we mean the same... i dont have the problem with inserting it... i have the problem with maintaining the association. so that every entry in this table A has a corresponding entry in table B. i want that the id of A is inserted in table B too.

Comment: Oops, sorry I got it wrong then, sorry, but as far as I know you cannot do call backs for individual records in mass assignment. But if you could tell you the business requirement, we might probably work on an alternative way :)

Comment: ;-) Okay... it is mostly for testing purposes, but i think it is very necessary.
For example, i have Table A with id and name, and i have Table B with id, address, A.id

Now when i do a insert, i got the method before_create, which adds an entry in Table B with A.id.

But if i do those sql inserts, i cant maintain this with this method.. and i cant say how i should do this correct.. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Hi, If I get you right, you are mentioning here is , B has a foreign key "A.id", that means 'A' has_many B's and 'B' is belongs to 'A', in that case you should have an after_create in 'A' , because once you save only you get the id of 'A'. Since you have said this is for testing might as well have a DB dump restored before you start testing (programatically), But I believe if you are doing unit level testing you will not need these kind of huge data set, let me know your comments :D

Comment: Yeah... mostly.. But "A has_one B" and "B belongs_to A" is it in my case.
Ok you are right with the after_create (but it worked already with before_create, strange)

No.. its a project, we should test some performance Issues with mysql and with postgres and with mongodb, so i have to insert a lot of data into my database...